# C++: Enum definition in class after usage

Tags: c++, class, enums, nested

Is there a general way how compilers handle enum definitions in a Class, as in, would it work to use the enum in `private:` but define it in a `public:` section afterwards?

code example:

```
class MyClass{
private:
  myEnum myMember;

public
  enum myEnum { A, B, C };

}
```

It seems to work using the gpp, but is this proper usage?

Comment: The enum will be undefined.

Comment: I think it's a terrible idea to mix privacy modifiers like this. It's bad style, unclear, and doesn't really make much sense. Why would you want to do this? Isn't this just bad style, period? Should questions like these have answers that should be considered?

Comment: What is `gpp`? If you mean the `cpp` pre-processor, it lets lots of things through that are not valid `C/C++` programs. For instance: `This is not a valid C/C++ program!`

Comment: @BigBadWolf Please show code that will compile. Your code will not compile because  identifier myEnum is undefined when the private section of the class is compiled.

Comment: @Cinch mixing privacy modifiers (like this and in general) is excellent style, makes intentions clearer and is very sensible, period.

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to do it the other way round

```
class MyClass{
 public:
  enum myEnum { A, B, C };

 private:
  myEnum myMember;
};
```

so you define the enum  before use. However, making the definition of the enum public, but storing it in private is fine - you might not want users to be able to write to `myMember` directly, but you'd want them to understand what it was if a class function returned a `myEnum`.

Answer (score 2):

If to write the class correctly that it would at least compile

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  enum myEnum { A, B, C };

private:
  myEnum myMember;
};
```

then there are two members in the class. The first one is a definition of type

```
  enum myEnum { A, B, C };
```

and it is public.
The second one is a definition of data member `myMember` of type `enum myEnum` that is private.

So users of the class can use type name `enum myEnum` and can not access directly data member myMember

A more interesting example when the type is defined as private but a data member of this type is defined as public. For example consider the following class definition

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  enum myEnum { A = 10, B, C };

public:
  myEnum myMember = A;
};
```

In this case you can not access the enumeration name. If you will try the following program

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
  enum myEnum { A = 10, B, C };

public:
  myEnum myMember = A;
};

int main() 
{
    MyClass c;

    myEnum x = c.myMember;
    //MyClass::myEnum x = c.myMember;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

you will get a compilation error. However you can deceive the compiler by replacing

```
myEnum x = c.myMember;
```

with

```
auto x = c.myMember;
```

The following program will compile

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
  enum myEnum { A = 10, B, C };

public:
  myEnum myMember = A;
};

int main() 
{
    MyClass c;

    auto x = c.myMember;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @tobi303 I am simply discussing the difference in the two approaches.

Comment: Well, and I am simply asking if there is any other use of this, other than "it compiles" :P Seriously, I would be interested to know what this approach could be used for. To me it looks like making it more complicated than necessary without reason, but maybe (actually most likely) I just dont see the point.

Comment: @tobi303  As far as I remember the second approach was used in some template definition. But now I do not remember it